# Should I include all of my columns from the select in my index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a query that is taking a bit to run it looks like this.

```
Select a.ColumnA,a.ColumnB,a.ColumnC,a.CoulmnD,a.columnE,...b.ColumnH
from Table A a
  inner join Table B b
       on a.columnB = b.ColumnB
  Where a.columnA = @VariableA
```

Now it has a clustered index on Table A like this

```
Clustered Index on ColumnA
```

It also has a nonclustered index on Table A like this

```
NonClustered Index on (ColumnA,ColumnB) include (ColumnC,ColumnD)
```

Should I add ColumnsE-G into the index as well?

Comment: can you include the execution plan

Comment: The more columns you include in your index, the more costly it is to use that index.  Presumably you hope by adding columns to avoid reading the base table at all, but if table A is large enough and your query hits only a small enough proportion of rows then it is probably cheaper to leave the extra columns out of the index.  The execution plan may help you determine whether you're in that regime, but if there's any uncertainty then *test*.

Comment: @ughai I dont have the execution plan at hand right now but, the part that is costing the most is the Clustered Index Scan on TableA, with the outputs being ColumnA-G. Which is puzzling to me because I would think that it should be doing a NonClustered Index Seek using the nonclustered index since Both my where clause and join condition are included in the index.

Comment: the reason it might be doing a clustered index scan is if the optimizer feels  too many rows are being returned and a non clustered seek with a key lookup would be more expensive. what kind of data does column A store? does the column store high range of distinct values or does it have mostly similar data? are your stats up to date? there are too many variables involved for us to give you a concise and correct answer

Comment: @ughai, my stats are up to day, column a is an unique int, column b is a guid, while the other two of the other columns are bits and the rest are varchar ranging from 10 to 50. I will post the execution plan as soon as I can.

Comment: that's interesting. column a is a unique column and yet optimizer choose a clustered index scan instead of a clustered index seek. execution plan may shed some light

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF, make sure the data type of the specified variable/parameter matches that of the underlying column.  I can see how a non-sargable expression would require a scan.

Comment: You can always figure this out with trial and error or using the query execution plan (best option). Like others have mentioned, if you include the Execution Plan we can suggest what to index on.

Comment: So im sorry for taking so long to answer, I was taken off this project at work. At the end it ended up being what @Dan Guzman suggest. There was casting and max functions involved in the Variable not matching the search column. Thank you very much, if you post your comment as answer I will gladly mark it as answer. Otherwise I would of never looked into the type of the variable compared to the actual table column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Verify the **data type** of *compared columns* and *parameters* are the same when you see an index scan instead of the expected seek in the execution plan.

When data types differ, SQL Server must first convert the operand with the lower precedence to the higher precedence data type (e.g. `varchar` to `nvarchar`).  When it is the column value that must be converted, the conversion prevents an index on a column from being used efficiently because the column value of each row must be converted before the comparison can be done.  This is known as a **non-sargable** expression and *prevents the more efficient index seek*.